# Dot after Reference in Body Mapping Template (AWS API Gateway)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, string-concatenation, vtl, apache-velocity

Is it possible to use a dot directly after a reference in API Gateway's Body Mapping Templates?

I do string concatination like this:

```
#set($region = "us-east-2")
#set($apiid = "$context.apiId")
#set($stage = "$context.stage")
#set($path = "search/stac")

"url": "https://$apiid.execute-api.$region.amazonaws.com/$stage/$path"
```

The problem is that $apiid and $region are not getting dereferenced. The result looks like this.

```
"url: "https:// .execute-api. .amazonaws.com/dev/search/stac
```

If I use the references without string concatenation they have the expected values. So the *#set* operation seems to be correct.

I assume it mistakes the dot after the reference as a function call.
How to escape the dots in Velocity Template Language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [curly braces](http://people.apache.org/~henning/velocity/htmlsingle/VelocityUsersGuide.html) to mark the beginning and end of variable:

```
"url": "https://${apiid}.execute-api.${region}.amazonaws.com/$stage/$path"
```

> If you need to explicitly separate a Velocity directive from surrounding text, it is possible to wrap it in curly braces ({ and }):

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks for your quick response.